# Button in Android Studio interacting with View

Tags: android

I am working on an android application with a DrawingView.

I would like to have a button which clears the drawing view, however I cannot figure out how to make a button that calls a method in somewhere that's not the MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

The above text is the only code in the main activity, so I do not have access to a reference of the drawingView.

```
public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
  super(context, attributeSet);

  AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            try {
                DrawingView dView = (DrawingView) objects[0];
                dView.connection = new Connection((DrawingView) objects[0], (Context) objects[1],new Socket("128.199.236.107", 3333));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
  };

  Object[] myObjects = new Object[2];
  myObjects[0] = this;
  myObjects[1] = context;
  myTask.execute(myObjects);

  getRes();
  setupDrawing();
```

This is the constructor of the class DrawingView.java
There is a method in this class called "refresh", and I am trying to call it using a button. Is there any way I can do this?

The refresh method looks like this

```
  public void refresh(){
      Canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
```

}

The MAIN ACTIVITY refresh method (called on the button press), looks like this

```
public void refresh(View v){
    final DrawingView DV = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);
    DV.refresh();

}
```

[Logcat? I think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du5Wl.png)

Comment: Why can you not reference the drawing view?

Comment: Are you essentially doing this? https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Painting-with-Views

Comment: There is no reference to it in the main activity. When I tried to look it up using findViewById(), it warned me that I was delaying the main thread.

Comment: In reply to xBroak, similar but more complex as there is a server component.

Comment: I think we're going to need more code form you here jezza a little too vague to help

Comment: Okay I'll edit the main question hold up

Comment: Can you also show how you were referencing it? It should be as simple as DrawingView myDrawingView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawView); myDrawingview.refresh(); UNLESS the actual function refresh has some UI blocking code in it. In which case we need to see the contents of refresh()

Comment: I tried DrawingView DV = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing); and it works, but the trouble is I'm trying to clear the graphics pane, and that won't work from a static context

Comment: Where is the static though? refresh does not need to be static afaik

Comment: If I call DV.refresh(), which my function inside the drawing view that clears the screen, it gives me an error Non-static method draw colour cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: `Non-static method draw colour`... That is a problem with code you have to [edit] your question to show us

Comment: Sorry! edited now

Comment: No. All the methods. And include the code that you used with findViewById. And show the logcat of the errors you saw that refer to the UI thread

Comment: I tried. It has too many methods, most irrelevant, for me to just paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

Make your shared method static by adding the "static" keyword:

```
public static void myFunction()
```

Then use:

```
Another Activity.myFunction();
```

One simpe way to cleanup your canvas is to insert this code on the OnDraw method:

```
Paint p=new Paint();
p.setARGB(255,100,120,140); // your background color
Rect r =new Rect();
canvas.getClipBounds(r);
canvas.drawRect(r,p);`
```

but it's better to perform the allocations of **r** and **p** outside of onDraw.

Comment: Hey, the problem is a static method cannot do what I want to do - clear the DrawingView.

Comment: OK, what view do you use? do you mean an custom ImageView?

Comment: public class DrawingView extends View is the code I used to create it. It's a custom ImageView. I'm using the code Canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR); to clear it